# Asking a detailed guideline to forece parameters as positional-only, positional- or keyword-argument, and keyword only when using *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, arguments, keyword-argument

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters

```
def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):
      -----------    ----------     ----------
        |             |                  |
        |        Positional or keyword   |
        |                                - Keyword only
         -- Positional only
```

According to the reference, / and * indicate the kind of parameter by how the arguments may be passed to the function: positional-only, positional-or-keyword, and keyword-only.

It is clear how to use it when I use normal positional arguments or keyword arguments. However, when I use `*args` or `**kwargs` together, it becomes very complicated to me.

for example,

```py
def func(a, *args, /):  # SyntaxError: / must be ahead of *
    pass
```

This code raise `SyntaxError: / must be ahead of *` although it is clear that `a` and `args` is positional parameters. I know / is unnecessary here, but what I am wondering is why the Error message is `SyntaxError: / must be ahead of *`. I used `*` for to point out `*args`, not independent `*`.

```py
def func(a, /, *args):  # No error!?
    pass
```

However, this code works without Error although `*args` is indicated as positioal- or keyword- arguments as it follows `/` (`*args` cannot take keyword arguments!). I think this should raise Error such as `SyntaxEror: *args cannot take keyword argument`.

In addition,

```
def func(*, **kwargs):  # SyntaxError: named arguments must follow bare *
     pass
```

This code raise `SyntaxError: named arguments must follow bare *`. I know in the function, `*` is unnecessary, but the error message says named arguments must follow bare * although the named arguments `**kwargs` is already following `*`.

I think I am missing something. So, it would very appreciate if anyone explain more detailed guideline to use `/` and `*` when using `*args` or `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is really simple: The error messages are weird, however, what works and what does not is really logical.
Keep in mind that, if you are using a mixture of tabs and spaces, you can get an `error: invalid constant.` The parser is not always able to see *why* something does not work. Also, you kind of misunderstand how `/` works.

`*args` eats up all positional arguments
`**kwargs` eats up all keyword arguments.

So, if you define a function like this:

```py
def func(a, *args, /):  # SyntaxError: / must be ahead of *
    pass
```

You're doing the same thing twice. `/` prohibits any more locational arguments, but `*args` already eats up all of them, so the slash is not needed.

Same goes for `*, **kwargs`. `*` just not needed.
This, however, does work:

```py
def hello(*, hello: str = "Hello", **kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
```

At this point, the * is needed, as otherwise `hello` could be passed positionally. This, therefore also works. The parser just checks if there is a definition to take variables after the `*`, and **kwargs does not, and this is not seen as a bug, because there is no need to use it that way.

Lastly, I agree that this:

```py
def func(a, /, *args):  # No error!?
    pass
```

Is weird code, but it does work:

the `/` prohibits anything *in front of it* to be passed as a keyword, and `*` mandates anything after it to be taken as a keyword. You can pass positional arguments after a `/`, and *args will eat those up.

This is perfectly valid python:

```py
def hello(a, /, *args):
    print(args)
    print(a)

hello("a", "b")
>>> ('b',)
>>> a
```

So, this is the order:

```
(positional, only, /, positional or keyword, [*args or *], keyword only, **kwargs)
```

Where, if you specify a `*` and then `**kwargs` without anything in between, it throws an additional error, because the * was not needed.

The error messages you get are indeed a bit weird, but it does all check out.

I hope that helps. :-)

Comment: Thx for the clear explanation. I thought argument between `/` and `*` should be passed in both ways, positional and keyword. Then, I think the error messages are needed to be updated. And it would be nicer if the documnet I referred is updated to be clearer.

Comment: Is there an official document that explain what you explained for me?

Comment: As far as I know, this is all just in the normal documentation as you already found it. It does not explicitly state how these two interact, but the way they will interact is all logical by simply going trough the exact rules they define step by step. :-)